# Algorithm for spliting a large graph on multiple pages

Tags: algorithm, printing, graphviz, dot, directed-acyclic-graphs

If I have a large DAG (namely, a family tree), I can generate a dot(1) code. How could I print such graph on the paper? With any moderately sized family, it would require splitting the result on multiple pages. I could imagine some kind of backtracking algorithm could help, but isn’t there some code actually written for this? I was searching all Googles, SO and I couldn’t find anything.

Any ideas (or even better URLs for the code)?

Update: yes, the point is to find the algorithm for splitting the large graph automatically into size appropriate sub-graphs.

I didn’t know about http://www.graphviz.org/content/FaqMultiPage … does it do what I would like to?

Comment: Are you able to break the nodes down into reasonable sub-graphs or are you looking for an automatic function to do that?

Comment: I assume [this](http://www.graphviz.org/content/FaqMultiPage) doesn't help?

Comment: @ChrisGerken automatic function to do the splitting is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Ancestry.com might have good answers for you. Try next two links:

- http://www.ancestry.co.uk/cs/Satellite?childpagename=UKLearningCenter%2FLearning_C%2FPageDefault&pagename=LearningWrapper&cid=1265124427564
- http://ancestryforums.custhelp.com/posts/fdd85ca1da